# Price rating approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new to web development and I don't know if my solution is OK according to the best practices, considering performance and clean code.

I have a Merchant model that belongs to a Price model.

Price table:

```
create_table "prices", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "price_range"
  t.integer  "percentile"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

The current values inside the table:

> ```
> **price_range**    **percentile **
> Up to $20.00            20
> $20.01 to $40.00        40
> $40.01 to $60.00        60
> $60.01 to $80.00        80
> More than $80.00       100
> ```

To show this at my view I'm using:

```html
<div class="price-ratings">
  <div class="empty-prices"></div>
  <div class="full-prices" style= width:"<%= "#{@merchant.price.percentile}%" %></div>
</div>
```

According to the width value the dollar signals will be colored (the CSS part of code is in the jsFiddle link).

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pknoll/dxdf8whv/)

I'm not sure about that approach. Can anyone recommend a finer solution to achieve the same or is that OK?

Answer (score 2):

Using a string column is not a very ideal solution. How would you for example query for rows where the price range is within or below 70.00$?

What if you want to do calculations in the database based on the values?

Instead you should use two columns:

```
create_table "prices", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.decimal   "price_min"
  t.decimal   "price_max"
  t.integer  "percentile"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

Note that when dealing with money you should use an integer in the lowest unit of currency (cents) or a decimal. See: [why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

You can even write a methods in your model to get/set price_range with a [range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html):

```
class Price
  def price_range
    (price_min..price_max)
  end 

  def price_range=(range)
    self[:price_min], self[:price_max] = range.begin, range.end
  end
end
```

If you are [using Postgres](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html) you can use the native range database type.

```
create_table :events do |t|
  t.numrange :price_range
  t.integer  "percentile"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

You can write a helper method to format it nicely

```
module PriceHelper
  def price_range_human( range )
    "$%s to $%s" % [range.begin, range.end].map(:number_to_currency)
  end
end
```

See [ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html)